# Blood test and infection probability

Tags: probability

If i take a blood test to check for a virus infection and  the probability that i have the virus given that the blood test is positive is $P(I|P)$ $\big\{$infected given blood test is positive $\big\}$ then what will the probability be if i take two test and they are positive?

Comment: HINT consider the probability of you not having the virus

Comment: It partly depends on whether the two tests are independent